# Loop through a pandas series with vectorization

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series like this:

```
0    something new
1    another thing
```

I would like to return an empty pandas dataframe if a certain condition is met. 
Right now Im using a for loop which shouldn't be used in cases like this because of the performance time:

```
for x in data:
    if len(x.split()) < n_words:
        return pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=[])
```

I would like to loop through it and have been looking into pandas vectorization and numpy vectorization but having trouble implementing it.

An advice into right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df['data'].str.split().str.len < n_words`

Comment: That said, the performance may not improve since most string-related functions in pandas are non-vectorized.